# Excel VBA decimal numbers get converted to integers in text output

Tags: vba, text, excel, precision

I have a spreadsheet, and I have written a macro which uses some of the values in the spreadsheet to output a text file. Everything works fine except one issue:

If I have a floating number like 15.0, it shows up in the output text file as integer 15, without the decimal point. I do not observe the same issue if the number after the decimal point is something other than zero, e.g., 15.1 gets written as 15.1; no problem there.

I wonder if there is some kind of a command or property, which would force all numbers are written to the output file as floating numbers?

This is the line I write the numbers to the text file. WeightList(i) and SpacingList(i) are string arrays, which are used for storing the numbers collected from the spreadsheet.

```
Print #1, Chr(9); "<truck axleW=" & Chr(34) & _
          WeightList(i) & Chr(34) & " axleS=" & _
          Chr(34) & SpacingList(i) & Chr(34) & "></truck>"
```

Thank you!

EDIT: This is the line where the numbers are converted to strings, I tried using the format command but this did not help:

```
WeightList(i) = Format("0.0", Truck(i).AxleWeights(i))
```

EDIT2: The code works now, after changing the order of the arguments in the format command. Please see the accepted answer for details.

Comment: Please edit your questino to include the code where you store the numbers collected into the string arrays; that's where the fix would have to be made.

Comment: To Excel there is no difference between 15 and 15.0 You could try to use something like `... & Format(WeightList(i),"#.0###") & ...` - the format string to use would depend on exactly what you want in your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `format(value,"0.0")` to convert to a string with the desired sig figs.

EDIT - sorry had order reversed...

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, or I may have messed up with the way it is supposed to be used. `WeightList(i) = Format("0.0", Truck(i).AxleWeights(1))` is the line I tried to convert the actual number to a string based on your suggestion. The output from the code above in the original question still gives integers.

Comment: @marillion - when I first posted this I had the order reversed... changed it to the correct order about 15 seconds later. You just missed it... `WeightList(i) = Format( Truck(i).AxleWeights(1), "0.0")` should do it; is WeightList declared as a string array?

Comment: it works now. funny thing is, it did not give any errors when I had the order switched :) Yep, WeightList is a string array, but the code works now, thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

How about the using `FormatNumber`

```
FormatNumber(value, 1)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt(v=vs.80).aspx